# Sorting array regardless of upper or lowercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am creating this sorting pipe for my angular project.
But it comes out as this.

```html
"BUNNY",
"Castle 111",
"TOTAL 2323 Test",
"Tower 2323 Test",
"Vivy",
"bayside"
```

I want to be
[bayside,BUNNY,Castle 111,TOTAL 2323 Test,Tower 2323 Test,vivy]
Here is my test code snippet
https://codesandbox.io/s/orderbypipe-bc7xx?file=/src/app/app.component.html:820-832

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the two strings by converting both to lowercase (with [`String.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)), then using [`String.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const arr = ["BUNNY",
  "Castle 111",
  "TOTAL 2323 Test",
  "Tower 2323 Test",
  "Vivy",
  "bayside"
]

const sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()))

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localeCompare` with `{sensitivity: 'accent'}` in the `sort` callback to ignore case.

```js
const arr=["BUNNY",
"Castle 111",
"TOTAL 2323 Test",
"Tower 2323 Test",
"Vivy",
"bayside"];
arr.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {sensitivity: 'accent'}));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: And if the Array to sort is BIG and performances start to matter, then they can even use a [Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator) with the same option.

Comment: Thanks. I work well for just javascript only file. But for my angular project that I mention above, it is not workng. https://codesandbox.io/s/orderbypipe-bc7xx?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ['b', 'A', 'e', 'C'];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `sortBy` method of `lodash` library for sorting the one-dimensional collection irrespective of the case.

- Install `lodash` and `lodash-es`

```js
npm install --save lodash

npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

- Modify the pipe as shown in the following snippet,

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { sortBy } from "lodash-es";

@Pipe({ name: "sortBy" })
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(
    value: T[],
    caseInsensitive = false,
    order = "",
    column: string = ""
  ): T[] {
    if (!column || column === "") {
      const sorted = this.sortOnCaseSensitivity(value, caseInsensitive);
      if (order === "asc") {
        return sorted;
      } else {
        return sorted.reverse();
      }
    }
    if (value.length <= 1) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  sortOnCaseSensitivity<T>(value: T[], caseInsensitive: boolean): T[] {
    return sortBy(value, (v: T) => {
      if (typeof v === "string" && caseInsensitive) {
        return v.toLowerCase();
      }
      return v;
    });
  }
  
}
```

- Call the created `sortBy` custom pipe in your template.html file as shown below,

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let word of words | sortBy: true:'asc'">{{ word }}</li>
</ul>
```

For your reference adding link to a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkchgd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)